# Dotnet watch failing in docker-compose

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I have recently had to update docker (2.2.0.0 stable 42247) and now I am having issues running `dotnet watch` in a docker container using `docker-compose`.

My workflow is to mount the solution directory (on the host) onto a docker container that runs `dotnet watch` on the relevant project, the initial version looked a little like so:

`./docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  my-api:
    build: 
      context: $MY_API_LOCATION_ON_HOST # the folder with the .sln file and all projects
      dockerfile: $DOCKERFILE_ROOT/Dockerfile-aspcore-dev
      args:
        PROJECT: app/src/MyApi # Where the .csproj will be
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: $MY_API_LOCATION_ON_HOST # the folder with the .sln file and all projects
        target: /app
      - type: bind
        source: $SECRETS_FOLDER # C:\Users\DevUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets
        target: /root/.microsoft/usersecrets
```

`./Dockerfile-aspcore-dev`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS base
ARG PROJECT
WORKDIR ${PROJECT}

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "watch", "run", "--urls", "http://0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

and it would run successfully. After the update I get the following error:

```
docker-compose up --build --force-recreate my-api
Building my-api
Step 1/4 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS base
 ---> 2fe8fe202baf
Step 2/4 : ARG PROJECT
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cee4bd05745b
Step 3/4 : WORKDIR ${PROJECT}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ed12fa68fc7e
Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "watch", "run", "--urls", "http://0.0.0.0:5000"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6c0b8b95cd8e
Successfully built 6c0b8b95cd8e
Successfully tagged src_my-api:latest
Recreating src_my-api_1 ... done
Attaching to src_my-api_1
my-api_1                 | System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.
my-api_1                 |    at Interop.Sys.GetCwdHelper(Byte* ptr, Int32 bufferSize)
my-api_1                 |    at Interop.Sys.GetCwd()
my-api_1                 |    at System.Environment.get_CurrentDirectory()
my-api_1                 |    at System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
my-api_1                 |    at Microsoft.DotNet.CommandFactory.CommandResolver.TryResolveCommandSpec(ICommandResolverPolicy 
commandResolverPolicy, String commandName, IEnumerable`1 args, NuGetFramework framework, String configuration, String outputPath, 
String applicationName)
my-api_1                 |    at Microsoft.DotNet.CommandFactory.CommandFactoryUsingResolver.Create(ICommandResolverPolicy commandResolverPolicy, String commandName, IEnumerable`1 args, NuGetFramework framework, String configuration, String outputPath, String applicationName)
my-api_1                 |    at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
my-api_1                 |    at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
src_my-api_1 exited with code 1
```

This output along with my temporary workaround suggest that it is something to do with not being able to figure out what the cwd or pwd is rather than an issue with dotnet watch. The work around looks like so:

`./docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  my-api:
+    tty: true
+    stdin_open: true
    working_dir: /app/src/MyApi # Where the .csproj will be
    build: 
      context: $MY_API_LOCATION_ON_HOST
      dockerfile: $DOCKERFILE_ROOT/Dockerfile-aspcore-dev
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: $MY_API_LOCATION_ON_HOST # the folder with the .sln file and all projects
        target: /app
      - type: bind
        source: $SECRETS_FOLDER # C:\Users\DevUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets
        target: /root/.microsoft/usersecrets
```

`./Dockerfile-aspcore-dev`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS base
ARG PROJECT
WORKDIR ${PROJECT}

- ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "watch", "run", "--urls", "http://0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

run:

```
docker-compose up --build --force-recreate search-api
Building search-api
Step 1/3 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS base
 ---> 2fe8fe202baf
Step 2/3 : ARG PROJECT
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cee4bd05745b
Step 3/3 : WORKDIR ${PROJECT}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ed12fa68fc7e
Successfully built ed12fa68fc7e
Successfully tagged src_search-api:latest
Recreating src_search-api_1 ... done
Attaching to src_search-api_1
```

then run:

```
docker exec -it src_my-api_1 dotnet "watch" "run" "--urls" "http://0.0.0.0:5000"
watch : Polling file watcher is enabled
watch : Started
watch : Exited
watch : File changed: /app/src/MyApi/Constants.cs
watch : Started
...
```

**additionally** running something like

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS base
ARG PROJECT
WORKDIR ${PROJECT}

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "fsx"]
```

will yield a very similar error

```
docker-compose up --build --force-recreate my-api
Building my-api
Step 1/4 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS base
 ---> 2fe8fe202baf
Step 2/4 : ARG PROJECT
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cee4bd05745b
Step 3/4 : WORKDIR ${PROJECT}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ed12fa68fc7e
Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "fsx"]
 ---> Running in eaa49fc2294c
Removing intermediate container eaa49fc2294c
 ---> f2f4f212d0e9
Successfully built f2f4f212d0e9
Successfully tagged src_my-api:latest
Recreating src_my-api_1 ... done
Attaching to src_my-api_1
my-api_1                 | System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.
my-api_1                 |    at Interop.Sys.GetCwdHelper(Byte* ptr, Int32 bufferSize)
my-api_1                 |    at Interop.Sys.GetCwd()
my-api_1                 |    at System.Environment.get_CurrentDirectory()
my-api_1                 |    at System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
my-api_1                 |    at Microsoft.DotNet.CommandFactory.CommandResolver.TryResolveCommandSpec(ICommandResolverPolicy 
commandResolverPolicy, String commandName, IEnumerable`1 args, NuGetFramework framework, String configuration, String outputPath, 
String applicationName)
my-api_1                 |    at Microsoft.DotNet.CommandFactory.CommandFactoryUsingResolver.Create(ICommandResolverPolicy commandResolverPolicy, String commandName, IEnumerable`1 args, NuGetFramework framework, String configuration, String outputPath, String applicationName)
my-api_1                 |    at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
my-api_1                 |    at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
src_my-api_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: We observed the same error and were only able to get around it by downgrading from 2.2.0.0 to 2.1.0.5 on a Windows host

Comment: I had the same issue on Windows 10.  Downgrading from 2.2.0.0 to 2.1.05 also fixed my error.

Answer (score 1):

I am not using the particular version and have seen github issue posts saying to drop your version to 2.1 something. However if anyone else comes along here is a 3.1.404 version that works that might point you in the right direction.

Dockerfile.dev

```yaml
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1.404-buster
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.sln ./
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","watch","run","--no-launch-profile"]
```

And the compose file

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
    aspnet_service:
        container_name: aspnet_dev_container
        restart: always
        hostname: api
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: ./Docker/api/Dockerfile.dev
        environment:
          - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+
          - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5001
          - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
        ports:
          - target: 80
            published: 5000
            protocol: tcp
            mode: host
      - target: 443
        published: 5001
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
        volumes:
          - ./:/app
          - ${APPDATA}\microsoft\UserSecrets\:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
          - ${USERPROFILE}\.aspnet\https:/root/.aspnet/https/
        working_dir: /app
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
        command: dotnet watch run --no-launch-profile
```

A little walk through, this docker-compose also lets you have https cert working locally if you would like that.
the Build: dockerfile section is just the path to my dockerfile, while the context is the root of the project.

The volumes

- ./:/app - all contents in the context are now a volume mount in the container at /app which is the workindir as declared in the Dockerfile
- the {APPDATA} volume is where the secret is stored locally I will show how to make that as well
- {USERPROFILE} I cant particularly remember at this moment but its related to the secret

The `--no-launch-profile` worked for me so I kept it over the `--no-restore` like I have seen in other project examples that failed me.

I couldn't find the post on how to get the https to work but if you would like me to edit this response and add it in please leave a comment and I will. I left it out since it is not related to the question.